# Add parent for each img with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, dom

I would like to add parent for each img with PHP.
I can do this with `wrap()` in jQuery  but I don't how to do with PHP.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="main">
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$("#main img").each(function(){ $(this).wrap('<div class="photo" />'); });
```

**RESULT HTML :**

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="photo"><img src="..." /></div>
  <div class="photo"><img src="..." /></div>
  <div class="photo"><img src="..." /></div>
  <div class="photo"><img src="..." /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eh? `oO` How do you generate the markup in PHP?

Comment: Why you want it to be done in PHP?
If you forcefully want this then you have to do it via string functions or regular expressions though. do you want code for that??

Comment: @KD Or using a DOM processor...

Comment: Why do you need to do this at all? There's very little to be gained from adding the extra markup. As far as CSS and JS is concerned, pretty much anything you could do to the `<div>` could be done just as easily to the `<img>` without needing a wrapper. That's not to say it's wrong; there are cases where it is necessary, but sometimes when asking "how do I do this?", it's better to think "should I do this?" or "is there another way?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the function I made below.

```
<?php
$page = '
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <img src="..." />
            <img src="..." />
            <img src="..." />
            <img src="..." />
        </div>
    </body>
';

echo $page = wrapImg ( $page, 0 );

function wrapImg ( $page, $offset )
{
    if ( FALSE !== ( $startImg = strpos( $page, '<img', $offset ) )
      && FALSE !== ( $endImg = strpos( $page, '/>', $startImg ) )
    ) {
        $before = '<div class="photo">';
        $after = '</div>';

        $start = substr( $page, 0, $startImg );
        $img = substr( $page, $startImg, $endImg+2-$startImg );
        $end = substr( $page, $endImg+2);

        $page = $start . $before . $img . $after . $end;
        $length = ($startImg + strlen( $before . $img . $after )-1);

        $page = wrapImg ( $page, $length );
    }

    return $page;
}
?>
```

The result will be :

```
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="photo"><img src="..." /></div>
            <div class="photo"><img src="..." /></div>
            <div class="photo"><img src="..." /></div>
            <div class="photo"><img src="..." /></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) could be your answer.